# Shortcut to widget/sidebar editing on the admin menu?

Tags: admin, sidebar

We have a sidebar consisting of some text.

The client/owner will want to change the sidebar text occasionally. Out of the box he'll have to do this by navigating:

-> Admin menu
-> Appearance
-> Widgets
-> look past the "Available Widgets" (all of which are irrelevant to him) to **Primary Sidebar** on the right hand side
-> Dropdown
-> *now he can edit the content*

He's going to be baffled that he can't edit this type of content as quickly and easily as he can a "Page". Or he'll forget where to find it.

Is there a way to add a link to our Primary sidebar to the main admin menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using standard WP featurs there's no shortcut. But you can workaround using a custom widget.

As example create a very simple widget, something like:

```
class MyPageWidget extends WP_Widget { 
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct( 'MyPageWidget', 'My Page Widget' );
    }
    function widget( $args ) {
        $page = get_page_by_path('sidebar-page');
        if ( ! empty($page) ) {
          echo $args['before_widget'];
          echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
          echo $args['after_widget'];
        }
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function() { register_widget('MyPageWidget'); } );
```

This few lines of code, add a new widget for your site, with no options, it simply display the content of a page that has the slug `'sidebar-page'`.

Now where you have your text widget, replace with this one.

Create a page and assign the slug 'sidebar-page'.

Now everything you add in that page is displayed in the sidebar: edit a sidebar widget text is simply as edit a page, in effects, it consists in just edit a page.

Comment: i'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are not really meant to be frequently edited. They are semi-static content meant to be configured on site setup and more or less left alone. If you have built a site that requires frequent widget edits, you've probably made a bad design decision. Without knowing the details of the project, it is hard to say.

One thing that you can do to reduce the confusion is [remove the widgets your client doesn't need](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget).

Comment: i'm sure it's possible we're using the wrong tool. i'll look at your link

Comment: I am fairly certain that you are using the wrong tool but your description is not sufficient to tell me what tool might be a better one.